# Баг на сайте

Tags: html, css

Почему на сайте (garrymania.ru) элементы у первой новости уходят вправо?

http://prntscr.com/2vxpfp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Или попробуйте `clearfix`. Чую я, что у вас элементы первой новости попали в поток текста новости.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите код. Возможно, есть незакрытые теги, либо закрытые неправильно.